# Variable converge to known distribution, then what about its likelihood function

Tags: likelihood, convergence, asymptotics

If we only know $X$ converge to normal distribution, then is it possible to obtain its likelihood function ? I know it is impossible to get the exact likelihood function.

However, can we claim that when sample size is large enough, then the likelihood function of $X$ can be defined based on normal distribution?

Comment: The likelihood function is a _function_ of the _parameter_ of the model, hence, as such it should at best converge to a stochastic process (if properly normalised in the sample size $n$).

Comment: The answer depends on the sense of convergence.  Unless the $X_i$ are absolutely continuous with densities converging to a Normal density, the likelihood function for any finite number of the $X_i$ could be arbitrarily nasty (differing hugely from a Normal likelihood).  So: what form of convergence do you have in mind?

Comment: Suppose you look at the probability of being at position $6$ after $100$ steps (each independently $\pm1$ with equal probability) of a random walk.  The distribution has mean $0$ and variance $100$ and is "roughly normal" and for a normal distribution with this mean and variance the density at $6$ would be about $0.0333$.  But the probability is actually ${100 \choose 53}/2^{100}\approx 0.0666$ - close to twice as high.  Why? Because after an even number of steps you must be an even distance from $0$, and the actual probability of being at $5$ is $0$.  There are more complicated examples.